# Why does nonlocal not create new outer variable (unlike global)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, global-variables

I've noticed a difference between the `global` and `nonlocal` keywords while reading the Python 3 tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

If I try the following code, it works:

```
# Does not need: spam = ''
def global_scope_test():
  def do_global():
    global spam
    spam = 'global spam'

  do_global()

global_scope_test()
print(spam)
```

Whereas the following does not:

```
def nonlocal_scope_test():
  # Needs: spam = ''
  def do_nonlocal():
    nonlocal spam
    spam = 'nonlocal spam'

  do_nonlocal()
  print(spam)

nonlocal_scope_test()
```

Why is `global` allowed to create new bindings in the global scope, while `nonlocal` isn't allowed to create new bindings in the outer scope? It seems like a weird quirk, given the similarities of the two functions. The tutorial did not seem to highlight the difference in the example, and I couldn't find any threads talking about it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for nonlocal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-nonlocal-stmt) is clear about it:

> Names listed in a nonlocal statement, unlike those listed in a global
>   statement, must refer to pre-existing bindings in an enclosing scope
>   (the scope in which a new binding should be created cannot be
>   determined unambiguously).